# Смена сессии

Tags: php

Такой вот вопросик, пользователь прошел авторизацию, а администратор (тобишь я), забыл скрыть авторизацию при уже наявной сессии, и уже вошедший пользователь, опять видет запрос на авторизацию, ВОПРОС: Может ли он взломать меня. Тоисть свой логин сессии поменять на логин админа?) Прошу прощения за столь глупый вопрос))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос и в правду не очень. Файлы сессии лежат на сервере, а в куках (если у вас через них работает) записан идентификатор сессии. Пока ваш идентификатор ни кто не узнает, под вами зайти не сможет, т.е. под админом.